# Mass/Bulk assign categories to posts

Tags: categories

I need to assign categories to about 200 posts in bulk. Each post would have a few categories. I have the post ID's along with the Category ID's for each post in a text file like this:

```
Post ID, Category ID, Category ID, Category ID
```

How could I setup a custom function inside `functions.php` to use `wp_set_post_categories` to do this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would need to parse your text file. Using [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) you can read a file line-by-line. For every line, you separate the comma-separated list of IDs by using explode. After that, it's a case of simply calling `wp_set_post_categories` where the post ID is the first element of the list of IDs, and the category IDs are the other elements.

```
$fh = @fopen( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/testfile.txt', 'r' );

if ( $fh ) {
    while ( ( $line = fgets( $fh ) ) !== false ) {
        // Separate by comma
        $ids = explode( ',', $line );

        // Remove leading and trailing spaces from post ID and category IDs
        array_walk( $ids, 'trim' );

        // Get and remove first element of the list of IDs, the post ID
        $postid = array_shift( $ids );

        // Set categories for the post
        wp_set_post_categories( $postid, $ids );
    }
}
```

Please note that `wp_set_post_categories` will assign the "Uncategorized" category to a post if an empty array is passed as the list of categories.

Comment: This worked like a charm from the get-go. Thank you!