# Mass/Bulk assign featured images to posts

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a text file with post ids and attachment ids like so:

```
post_id,attachment_id
post_id,attachment_id
post_id,attachment_id
post_id,attachment_id
```

I then try to use a function inside my functions.php file like so:

```
function addimg() {
$fh = @fopen( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/addimg.txt', 'r' );

if ( $fh ) {
    while ( ( $line = fgets( $fh ) ) !== false ) {
        $ids = explode( ',', $line );
        array_walk( $ids, 'trim' );
        $postid = array_shift( $ids );
        set_post_thumbnail( $postid, $ids );
    }
}
}
add_action('wp_head', 'addimg');
```

But nothing happens.

I've used the same procedure to [add categories to posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139397/mass-bulk-assign-categories-to-posts) and it works. I've also tried to manually add a featured image to a post like so:

```
function thumb() {

set_post_thumbnail( 1, 1);

}
add_action('wp_head', 'thumb');
```

And that works.

So my knowledge is too shallow to understand why what I'm trying to do doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Can the file actually be openend (does the function every reach the `while`-loop)? Are lines actually being read? By the way, using `array_walk` this way generates a notice, if I remember correctly, because of the number of arguments. `array_map` would be suited better.

Comment: I'm afraid my skills don't go as far as debugging. Can the same operation be performed from within the `functions.php` without the need of an external text file? Like create some array with `post_id => attachment_id` and then for each pair `set_post_thumbnail`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't have much programming experience, I'll post a ready-to-use solution here. I've looked at your code a little longer, and the problem is that after `array_shift`, `$ids` is still an array. `set_post_thumbnail` expects and integer, not an array. You could use `$ids[0]` as the second parameter, but the following is a cleaner solution, in my opinion.

```
function wpse149149_addimg() {
    $fh = @fopen( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/addimg.txt', 'r' );

    if ( $fh ) {
        while ( ( $line = fgets( $fh ) ) !== false ) {
            $ids = explode( ',', $line );
            array_walk( $ids, 'trim' );
            set_post_thumbnail( $ids[0], $ids[1] );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse149149_addimg' );
```